# How to fix ‘No such file or directory’ error in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to run a php website on my localhost using xampp, but keep getting a 'No such file or directory' this is the warning i get:-

> Warning: require_once(D:/wamp/www/ntany3/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ntany3\index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:/wamp/www/ntany3/system/startup.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\ntany3\index.php on line 17

```
// Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');
```

Comment: did you go to that path to make sure that file is there?

Comment: I think you will find that is WAMPServer and not XAMPP

Comment: DIR_SYSTEM is not built-in constant

Comment: @treyBake yes I checked the file is there.

Comment: @alexmugo99 so copy and pasting D:/wamp/www/ntany3/system/startup.php into your terminal / explorer shows the file?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add the path relative to current directory, like this:

```
require_once(__DIR__. '/system/startup.php');
```

Put below code in a new file and name it path.php Then upload it to your root directory and go www.example.com.com/path.php

and it'll tell you the full path.

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
echo "<p>Full path to this dir: " . $dir . "</p>";
echo "<p>Full path to a .htpasswd file in this dir: " . $dir . "/.htpasswd" . "</p>";
```

Take that path and edit both config files .

Comment: @alexmugo99  Check updates please. I have updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `httpd.conf` (it's [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) config file) and edit it:

Where you have:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
```

Change to:

```
DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www"
```

Your errors happen because you are getting the wrong path, this happens because your `DocumentRoot` in your apache config is pointing to an non-existent path...

I suggest you to use full path... eg:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ntany3/system/startup.php");
```

Hope this helps.